# How do I paste a screenshot to Writer?

Tags: gnome, libreoffice, screenshot, paste

When I take a screenshot with say Alt + Printscreen and Ctrl + V in LibreOffice Writer, out comes only text 'screenshot'.
How do paste actual image to Writer? I know the screenshot is taken due the flash and sound.

Answer (score 1):

You should click on the `Copy to Clipborad` Button on the left-bottom corner of `Save Screenshot` dialog box. As follows:

[image]

Comment: What dialog box? I use shortcut keys Alt + PrintScreen to take screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/screen-shot-record.html

Here is the part of the content of the page above:

```
Prt Scrn to take a screenshot of the desktop.
Alt+Prt Scrn to take a screenshot of a window.
Shift+Prt Scrn to take a screenshot of an area you select.
```

When you use a keyboard shortcut, **the image is automatically saved in your Pictures folder in your home folder** with a file name that begins with Screenshot and includes the date and time it was taken."